# Why not in a dictionary of boolens is understood as a function call?

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

I have the following

```
class ShowOptions(Enum):
    MenuBBoxes =0
    Show_A = 1
    Show_B =2
    Show_C =3
    Show_D =4

isShown = { ShowOptions.MenuBBoxes: True,
            ShowOptions.Show_A: True,
            ShowOptions.Show_B:True,
            ShowOptions.Show_C:True,
            ShowOptions.Show_D:True}
```

I am trying to switch the values of the booleans such as

```
isShown[(h-1)]= not   isShown[(h-1)]
```

but this gives me the error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why not can not be used.
Note: if I do

```
  isShown[(h-1)]= not (1==0)
```

no problem occur

Comment: Post something that runs and reproduces the error when run. The code you've posted has entirely different issues from the bug you're asking about.

Comment: Works fine if I try to implement what you are saying here. But your code does not run directly so downvoting for now.

Comment: Can you define `h`?

Comment: @HenryEcker h is an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of your `dict` are `Enum` not `int`. You can't use them interchangeably. If you want to access something from the `dict` you need to use either the `Enum` definition like:

```py
from enum import Enum


class ShowOptions(Enum):
    MenuBBoxes = 0
    Show_A = 1
    Show_B = 2
    Show_C = 3
    Show_D = 4


isShown = {ShowOptions.MenuBBoxes: True,
           ShowOptions.Show_A: True,
           ShowOptions.Show_B: True,
           ShowOptions.Show_C: True,
           ShowOptions.Show_D: True}


isShown[ShowOptions.MenuBBoxes] = not isShown[ShowOptions.MenuBBoxes]
print(isShown)
```

If you want to use their value, you have to call your Enum type like:

```py
isShown[ShowOptions(0)] = not isShown[ShowOptions(0)]
print(isShown)
```

I think you were looking for something like:

```py
isShown[ShowOptions(h - 1)] = not isShown[ShowOptions(h - 1)]
```